# C++ Exceptions - Is throwing c-string as an exception bad?

Tags: c++, exception

I am working on a small c++ program and learning exceptions. Is the following code "bad", and if so, what can I do to improve it?

```
try {
    // code
    if (some error) {
        throw "Description of error.";
    }
}
catch (char* errorMessage) {
    cerr << errorMessage << endl << "Fatal error";
}
```

Is there anything wrong with throwing a `char` array as an exception?

EDIT:
Would this be a better way to go?

```
const char errorMessage[] = "Description of error";

try {
    // code
    if (some error) {
        throw errorMessage;
    }
}
catch (char* errorMessage) {
   cerr << errorMessage << endl << "Fatal error";
}
```

Comment: A more searchable title might be "C++ - is it bad to throw a string as an exception?".

Comment: @Merlyn That is not a std::string, but a c-type string

Comment: @VJo: The point is that the title isn't searchable, and I think it would be good to change it.  But to address your point, I think "string" is commonly used to refer to a std::string or one of the many variants of char*, and looking at the accepted answer, it would still be applicable to the question being asked.

Comment: Good practice is usually to always catch exceptions by const reference (`const &`).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It is much better to throw a standard exception object. In general, the best practice is to throw something derived from `std::exception` so that if in some situation it does cause your program to terminate, the implementation has a better chance of printing a useful diagnostic.

Because it isn't hard to do this, I would never recommend throwing a raw string literal.

```
#include <stdexcept>

void someFunction()
{
    try {
        // code
        if (some error) {
            throw std::runtime_error( "Description of error." );
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << "\nFatal error" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes and no. std::exception does offer additional flexibility, but comes with additional allocation when copying the string, and thus with a possibility of double exception fatality. Literals have an advantage of never throwing.

Comment: @GeneBushuyev: This is a potential concern, but if such a minimal allocation fails you are normally in a very bad way anyway. If I was in a situation where this was more than a theoretical concern, I would probably still use a true exception object derived from `std::exception` whose overloaded `what()` returned a pointer to a literal string. Space for an exception object (even if only a pointer) always has to be allocate and the exception object initialized whenever an exception is thrown.

Comment: @Charles: while I agree with throwing `std::exception`-derived objects anyway,  re "Space for an exception object (even if only a pointer) always has to be allocate and the exception object initialized whenever an exception is thrown." - it's possible for the heap to be exhausted (and thus `std::string` be unable to `new`), without the stack being exhausted (which is all that's necessary for a pointer)....

Comment: @Tony: Where do you think the exception object is stored? Stack doesn't seem to make sense so the pointer must be stored elsewhere. It might not be the heap, it might be a special reserved memory area. A good implementation might reserve space for the maximum size of exception ever thrown so that `throw` never fails. Whether that's a pointer or an object that can be initialized without allocating further heap memory now makes no difference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Charles. Just to clarify, if I do it using a `run_time` error the string gets put on the heap, and if I do it using a raw string it refers to the string which is already on the stack?

Comment: @GeneBushuyev Where did you find this.  `std::exception` doesn't contain a string (or shouldn't---what it actually contains is, of course, implementation dependent).  For exceptions which might be thrown when resources are limited, you can derive directly from `std::exception`, and override `what` to return a constant string.  (This is what is what I would expect from `std::bad_alloc`, for example.)

Comment: @Tim: A `std::runtime_error` stores the string that it is constructed with. Usually (but not necessarily), this will involve dynamically allocated memory. A literal string has static storage duration. If you throw something that pointed to an object with automatic storage duration (e.g. a `char` array "on the stack") and that object was not in scope in the exception handler then you would have a serious potential error.

Comment: @Charles: I expect the implementation to have a small supplementary stack for use during exception handling.  Call it a "special reserved memory area if you like"... fine.  Your postulated good implementation might find `max(sizeof` thrown objects`)`, but that still can't assess the needs of pointers from those objects that may at run-time handle heap, so it's ideal not to have any.

Comment: @Tony Certainly.  But not `std::exception`.  You can derived from `std::exception` to create exceptions which do not require dynamically allocated resources, for special cases where resources are tight.

Comment: @James: yes, agreed. Was just explaining where the concern came from, given the answer illustrates `std::runtime_error`.  IMHO, typical non-embedded server systems can rarely recover from such memory exhaustion, and assuming they're 64 bit with plentiful swap they'll slow down massively beforehand as virtual memory constraints kick in, so there's limited value in being so careful.

Comment: @Charles: would the edit in the question be a better way to go about it?

Comment: @Tim: I don't see a significant difference between either approach (other than the new snippet has an extra object that you need to ensure has the appropriate lifetime). I'd prefer a true exception object every time. Note that both snippets are in error because you can't catch a `const char*` with a `catch( char* )`.

Comment: @James: True, the standard doesn't require std::exception to be anything but the base class. But the most used implementation (DW) actually goes beyond the standard interface adding constructor `exception(const char * const &)` which makes malloc and copies the string. Even if they didn't do it, they would have to do this allocation in every descendant class.

Comment: Of the two implementations I have access to, g++ doesn't put anything in
`std::exception`, and only has a default contructor, and DM offers a
choice of constructors: only one of which allocates memory.  It's
essential that derived classes like `std::bad_alloc` can be constructed
without any resource allocation.  It's only the more complex exception
types in `<stdexcept>` which require dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 11):

Throwing a string literal *is* generally a bad idea because, as the code evolves, programmers may need to enrich the error message with some more information, e.g. the value of a variable, or the line number from which the exception is thrown.

Given unknown client code that's catching `const char*`, the programmer's encouraged to use a more dynamic mechanism to concatenate desired information:

- a `std::string` and `+`
- a `std::ostringstream`
- a char buffer and perhaps `strcat` and/or `sprintf()`

The most obvious ways of using these don't work or don't work well:

```
// temporaries...
throw (std::string("couldn't parse input: ") + input).c_str();
throw (static_cast<std::ostringstream&&>(std::ostringstream() << "error line " << __LINE__)).str().c_str();
char buf[1024]; sprintf(buf, "error line %ld%", __LINE); throw buf;

// not thread-safe
static char buf...
```

Even if the programmer knows not to do any of these, they'll still have a right time finding all the client code that needs to start accepting a richer value type, especially if other `throw`/`catch` usage of `const char*` persists.

So, using a class that embeds a flexible `std::string` description *by value* is very important for writing maintainable code.

Answer (score 4):

No there is problem with throwing a `char` array. Just that you should receive as,

```
catch(const char* const errorMessage) {...}
```

1st `const` is to add ability to receive any `char` array `char*` `const char*` `char[]` `const char[]`

2nd `const` is to specify that `errorMessage` is not intended to change within `catch` block

Comment: double const? (more chars needed)

Comment: second `const` is to intend that, `errorMessage` is not supposed to change.

Comment: It is perfectly legal, but not a best practice.  See Charles's answer.

Comment: @iammilind: top level constants on function parameter are considered bad practice (see Sutter's Coding Standards)

Comment: @Gene: how's that relevant? (these aren't function parameters)

Comment: @Tony The mechanism is very much like that used for function parameters.  It's pass by copy.

Comment: @James: yes - but the only reason I can think of right now to avoid `const` on function parameters is to preserve implementation freedoms without introducing recompilation dependencies (physical dependencies in Lakosian terms)... which doesn't apply here.

Comment: @Tony I think the reason is to maintain coherence between the declarations and the definition, while not exposing the internal details (the const-ness).  The alternative, IMHO, would be to ban the const on the declarations, but use it on the definition (but I think one compiler rejects this, even if it is legal).  Anyway, you're right that it doesn't apply here: there is no externally visible declaration, separate from the catch block.

Answer (score 1):

There is the general issue of not being able to easily filter your exceptions and act on them based on type. However, i don't know if there is a C++ specific reason not to do it

Answer (score 1):

std::exception (or at least, std::runtime_error) contains a string, that can be accessed through the what() method. Best thing you can do is to use that, since it's standard, and other code can expect it, and since it serves your purpose anyway.

Better stick to the standard in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If your idea of throwing a string as an error was for convenience of showing the error to the user, consider that this would make localizing your application more difficult (may or may not be a concern to you though).

Also if another part of the application needs to understand what the error is so it can react to it (eg if it is a disconnect error, try to reconnect automatically, but if it's a password error, just show error message to the user), it is better to have some sort of error code available to the exception catcher.

In our app, our exceptions are derived from std::exception.  They contain an error type (an enum), a debug error message (including file/line number), and a localized error string.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is much more simpler. :).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    try {
        throw runtime_error("This is an Error"); 
    }catch (exception& e){
        cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << endl; 
    }
    return 0; 
}
```