# Throwing a value in c++ if it is null

Tags: c++

I am trying to check a character pointer is null .How to check if the value is null i am basically from java

```
char* mypath = getenv("MYPATH");
if(!mypath) //this is not working
   throw "path not found";
if(mypath == NULL) //this is also not working
       throw "path not found";
```

i am getting an exception "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'"

Comment: The compiler does not know what to do with the exception of type `char const*` - You need to define a `catch`-clause which catches `char const*`-exceptions.

Comment: Coming from Java, you will be dismayed to learn that the result of an uncaught exception in C++ isn't that the program prints a stacktrace and exits. It just terminates. About the only good news is that you might be able to configure your debugger to break when an uncaught exception is thrown, so you're left looking at the throw site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem isn't the test: both of your `if` are correct (as far as the compiler is concerned—the second is preferable for reasons of readability).  The problem is that you're not catching the exception anywhere.  You're throwing a `char const[13]`, which is converted to a `char const*` as the type of the exception, and you don't have a `catch ( char const* )` anywhere in the calling code.

In C++, it's usual (but not at all required) to only throw class types derived from `std::exception`; about the only exception to this rule is to throw an `int` for program shutdown, and then only if that is the documented convention in the context where you work.  (It only works correctly if `main` catches `int` and returns the value.)

Answer (score 6):

You need to use a try/catch block in order to catch the exception and handle it.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  try {
    throw "test";
  }
  catch (const char *s) {
    printf("exception: %s\n", s);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Please note that throwing a C string as an exception is really not appropriate. See [C++ Exceptions - Is throwing c-string as an exception bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248404/c-exceptions-is-throwing-c-string-as-an-exception-bad/6249350#6249350) as commented by @Jefffrey for a discussion on that along with alternatives.