# Fix a return issue.Warning: control reaches end of non-void function in C++

Tags: c++, exception, return

I know this may look as a duplicate, but the other questions does not have the answer that I am looking for.

```
template <class T>
T Queue<T>::pop_back()
{
    try
    {
        if (empty())
            throw "The Queue is empty!";
        size--;
        back= (back- 1 + max_size) % (max_size);
        return queue[back];
    }
    catch (char* strException)
    {
        cerr << "Error: " << strException << endl;
    }
}
```

I have the above implementations of functions pop_back. Every time it removes the element it has to return that element. However, every time it tries to pop something from an empty Queue it says " terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'
Aborted (core dumped)"

What are some tips and advice to fix this issue? I have a try catch block there but it is not helping much. The functions has to return something, or stop and return to main, from where it was called.

I am looking for a design patter so I can used it other times I encounter such a problem.
Basically what should I do when I need to return something but there is nothing I can return?

Thank you.

Comment: If you are serious about exceptions, make some classes instead of throwing pointers to string literals. If you don't handle the exception, don't even bother catching it.

Comment: Throwing an exception for that is pretty questionable. Is it truly exceptional? And you can do the "Error:" message thing inside the if statement, don't add unnecessary overhead. Consider returning a null pointer in the case of there being no remaining elements in the container.

Answer (score 3):

You should not catch the exception in the function itself - the exceptions should be used to communicate the problem to the callers - they're the ones who should know what's sensible handling in this situation.

> The functions has to return something, or stop and return to main, from where it was called.

Not exactly - as above, it can `throw` and be continued from the `catch()` block most closely enclosing the place from which it was called.

Keep in mind that caller's who'd rather not do exception handling could easily test `empty()` or `size()` before deciding to attempt the pop... so it's quite reasonable to `throw` the exception back to them.

Further, don't throw a string literal... use a `std::runtime_error("...")` instead.  Reasons [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248404/c-exceptions-is-throwing-c-string-as-an-exception-bad/6249350#6249350).

> I am looking for a design patter so I can used it other times I encounter such a problem. Basically what should I do when I need to return something but there is nothing I can return?

As mentioned, throwing an exception is a normal way to deal with this, especially for something like pop from an empty stack.  More generally though, other alternatives include:

- return a sentinel value

  - for example, if the container stores `int`s, you might be able to return `0` or `-1` or [`numeric_limits<int>::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max), or for `std::string`s perhaps an empty one, but what would be best depends on the usage to which the client code puts the container
  - for a templated container it's hard to know whether a value of `T` can be used for this - for example if `T` is `char` and content from a binary file is being stored in the container, any character value you might want to use as a sentinel might also appear in the file; if you want to try this anyway, it's usually best to ask the caller to provide a sentinel value as a template parameter or constructor parameter.
- return a [`std::optional<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional) (still pending standardisation but might be offered by some compilers) or [`boost::optional<T>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)
- return a `std::pair<bool, T>` where `.second` is only the popped value if `.first` is `true`, indicating success
- return a [smart] pointer, but that's clumsy as you may have to dynamically allocate memory for a copy of the popped value; a smart pointer helps ensure the caller `delete`s the object later
- just document that the caller must check `empty()` or `size()` first, and [`assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert)ing that the container's not empty from within `pop_back` - this would halt the program if this "precondition" is not met by the caller
- change the interface to `bool pop_back(T& t)` where the return value indicates success and that caller-specified `T` parameter will have been set.

None of these are worthy of being called "patterns" - patterns tend to refer to more complicated, high-level design aspects.

Comment: You suggest to have a try catch in the main or driver?

Comment: @user2512806: yes, put it there instead of inside `pop_back`.

Comment: That is a good idea. the problem is that I wont be the one writing the driver. Someone else will write it and they may or may not have an exceptions handling. 
That is why i am trying to handle it here.

Comment: @user2512806 Well, client code should test the documented API - it should be considered their mistake if they don't catch your exceptions.  If you have to pander to them for some reason, do consider one of the other options listed at the bottom of my answer... e.g. a sentinel value or `optional<T>`.  I added `bool pop_back(T& t)` as another option....

Answer (score 2):

Replace the current code

```
template <class T>
T Queue<T>::pop_back()
{
    try
    {
        if (empty())
            throw "The Queue is empty!";
        size--;
        back= (back- 1 + max_size_) % (max_size);
        return queue[back];
    }
    catch (char* strException)
    {
        cerr << "Error: " << strException << endl;
    }
}
```

with something like this:

```
template< class Type >
auto Queue<Type>::pop_back()
    -> Type
{
        if( empty() ) { throw std::runtime_error( "The Queue is empty!" ); }
        --size;
        back = (back - 1 + max_size_) % (max_size_); // Note fix of name
        return queue[back];
}
```

You want to throw the exception *to the caller*.

Using an exception within the function, to just jump to the code that outputs some text (and fails to return a function result), doesn't make sense.

---

In passing, it's a good idea to standardize on *a single naming convention* for members. The inadvertent mixing of `max_size_` and `max_size`, which was most probably a bug, and anyway a serious imperfection, would not have happened with a single naming convention. And as it is, `back` as a data member is inconsistent with `max_size_`.

---

Also note the use of `std::runtime_error` instead of a string literal as the exception object. This supports catching of a `std::exception`. You might find some other standard exception class more suitable, more indicative of the particular problem, but I generally just use `std::runtime_error`.

Another reason why it's a good idea to use the *standard exception classes* is that it's otherwise easy to specify the wrong type in a `catch`.

For example, the `catch` in your code *would not have worked*:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void foo()
{
    try
    {
        throw "Blah blah!";
    }
    catch( char* s )
    {
        cout << "Caught exception internally in foo(): " << s << endl;
        return;
    }
}

auto main() -> int
{
    try
    {
        foo();
    }
    catch( ... )
    {
        cout << "Failed to catch exception in foo()." << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Failed to catch exception in foo().
```

Comment: Why wouldn't this work? 
According to this tutorial it should catch the exceptions within the first time it sees.
[link](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/153-exceptions-functions-and-stack-unwinding/)

Comment: A literal string of type `const char[N]`. Used as argument to `throw` it decays to `const char*`. That type can't be caught by a `char*`, just as you can't pass a `const char*` to a `char*` formal function argument.

Answer (score 1):

Precissely the issue is that you have try-catch block.

If an exception is thrown, execution flow will go to the catch logic. It will print your statement, and the function will end without returning a value.

Re-throw the exception of add a `return` statement, either at the end of the catch block or at the end of the function (rethrowing seems the best option, since you do not handle the exception at all).

Comment: Okay if I add a return statement what would that be? I cant return anything I want. And being a template it makes it even harder depending on the type.

Comment: The tutorial you mention in other comments is wrong. You catch exceptions at a level at which you can do anything about them. Your code is a good example of why; if you catch and hide the exception you are forcing your function to return a value that is inherently wrong. The client code calling your function will be the one to know if the exception may be ignored or is a signal of a programming failure elsewhere.

Comment: I didn't know that was wrong, thanks for letting me know. So, basically you are saying that I should throw an exceptions but I should not try to catch it. The client (driver , main) should catch the exceptions and handle it accordingly. Is that what you are trying to imply?